# How do I adjust the renderer to get the same result as on this sketchfab preview?

Tags: rendering, texturing, lighting

I'm trying to render [this model](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/old-tree-5793911821d04f73926ac4ab1d46727a) in Blender 2.93, but my results are not the same as the original on the website. I've tried changing the lighting settings, with evee and cycles, but im not an expert so it gets even worse. Does anyone know how to achieve the same?

Original:
[image]

My result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leaves in the Sketchfab render have translucency. This reduces the shadow they cast on each other and makes them brighter.

In Blender, you can use *Subsurface Scattering* to get a similar effect.

Both examples use the [Syferfontein 1d Clear](https://polyhaven.com/a/syferfontein_1d_clear) HDRI and a *Sun* light, strength 7 (see screenshot 2).

**Eevee Test Render**
Material *leaf old tree*: Subsurface Scattering: `0.1`; Color (hex): `CBDA84`
Material *old treetop*: Subsurface Scattering: `0.3`; Color (hex): `8C9B29`

[image: material settings for eevee]

[image: eevee example]

**Cycles Test Render**
with a little variation in the subsurface scattering.
Material *leaf old tree*: Subsurface Scattering: `0.2`; Color (hex): `8C9B29`
Material *old treetop*: Subsurface Scattering: `0.3`; Color (hex): `8C9B29`

[image: cycles example]

Comment: looks much better, i will try it, thanks bro!